# Python Apscheduler is not shutting down

Tags: python, shutdown, apscheduler

We have a requirement to schedule multiple jobs dynamically while current job is executing.

Approximate Scenario is:

There should be a scheduler to go through a table of application daily basis (assume at 6 AM UTC).
Find the users who has today's datetime as resume_dttime
Dynamically schedule a job for that user and start his service at that today's resume_dttime
So the my code is:

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
sched = BlockingScheduler()

def scheduled_job():
    """
    """
    liveusers = todays_userslist() #Get users from table with todays resume_dttime
    for u in liveusers:
        user_job = get_userjob(u.id)
        runtime = u.resume_dttime #eg u.resume_dttime is datetime(2015, 12, 13, 16, 30, 5)
        sched.add_job(user_job, 'date', run_date=runtime, args=[u.name])


if __name__ == "__main__":
  scheduled_job()
  sched.start()
  sched.shutdown(wait=True)
```

Code works well (for one job). Not checked with multiple jobs, but it doesn't stop at all.  I tried removing for loop. Also,have gone through the many queries on [google](https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=FGyGVuGhFe7I8AfaxaDoCQ#safe=active&q=apscheduler%20not%20shutting%20down). But no luck :( 
To Exit, every time, I need to exit through `CTrl+C`

Comment: where the code block? during the running scheduler or before? can you send traceback of your CTRL-C?

Comment: I don't understand why blocking wouldn't be the intended behavior. The role of a scheduler is to run in the background and occasionally launch a job, am I missing something ? cron is the only alternative to background running to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It blocks at start() as the [documentation](http://apscheduler.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/schedulers/blocking.html#module-apscheduler.schedulers.blocking) says. The start() call will only return if the scheduler is shut down from another thread, which you're not doing anywhere (judging from the above snippet).

Comment: Okay,Thanks,  Got you! So it will never come at   `sched.shutdown(wait=True)`.  Can you please show me an example to shut it down through another thread?

Comment: Shut it down from one of your scheduled jobs maybe? Just call sched.shutdown() there.